# Create a temp table, loop and add data and select from it? query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a temp table, and am fetching data from multiple tables and inserting data into it. When I try to get the data back from the table I get an error

> [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

```
do
$$
    DECLARE
        sampleproductId   varchar;
        productIds        text[] := array [
            'abc1',
            'abc2'
            ];
        tId              varchar;
        DECLARE result  jsonb;
        DECLARE resultS jsonb[];
    begin
       CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_temp_mapping
        (
            accountid      int,
            productUID      varchar,
            sampleproductId text
        );
        FOREACH sampleproductId IN ARRAY productIds
            LOOP
                tId := (select id
                        from product.product
                        where uid = sampleproductId);
                INSERT into product_temp_mapping (accountid, productUID, sampleproductId)
                select accountid, tId, sampleproductId
                from product.accountproductmap
                where productId = cast(tId as int);
            END LOOP;
        select * from product_temp_mapping;
    end ;
$$;
```

Is this the right way to do it? This is the first time I am doing something with a temp table

Comment: why have you tagged mysql and postgresql ? which one is it?

Comment: The issue is this `select * from product_temp_mapping;` The overriding issue is you cannot `RETURN` anything from a  anonymous(`DO`) function, which I assume is what you are trying to do. The next issue is that even if you do this in a regular function you need to, as the error states, assign the output of the `SELECT` to something.

Comment: Why the temp table at all? This can be done more efficiently with just one single SELECT statement

Comment: "Is that the right way to do it" is a rather broad question. I should answer "no".